# Open website on Wireguard host

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, port-forwarding, wireguard

Setup:

- Ubuntu 22.04 server
- Wireguard host
- Samba
- Tomcat
- UFW is enabled
- Both Samba and Tomcat/8080 are allowed from anywhere

I can open the Tomcat website on the local network (192.168.1.23:8080). I cannot open the website when on the VPN, via the VPN IP (192.168.5.1:8080). This results in a connection timeout. Samba however works via VPN.

How can I visit the website via Wireguard VPN?

I don't want all traffic to be routed through the VPN.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you locate a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if Tomcat is not binding to the IP address of the VPN.

Do you need to modify server.xml to remove the "address=" directive or replace the current directive with "*" ?